# No incoming file content shown in VSCode for a renamed file that causes a merge conflict while rebasing

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-rebase, git-merge-conflict

I have an older version of a software project where I did some changes (*feature* branch).
I want to include those changes in a new updated version of the software project (*main* branch), but without including changes to *feature* by other people.
So I decided to try an interactive rebase of *feature* onto *main* by just selecting my own commits that were done on the *feature* branch.

During the rebase there were some conflicts due to changes of some code lines by me that were also changed in the new project version. They could so far easily be resolved within VSCode by
selecting the changes I want from the current and/or incoming view.

However, one particular conflict just shows an empty file in the incoming view, which makes it not possible to include the changes I have made in the commit.

I analyzed the properties of the file that caused the merge conflict.

In *feature* there is a file (*old.txt*) that I made some changes to. To the same file also some changes were made in  *main*, but it also got renamed
(*renamed.txt*) and moved to a different folder.

When hovering over the file *renamed.txt* in the source control view (Merge Changes) it shows: "Conflict: Both Modified".
In the current view, it highlights all the changes of the new project version since the merge-base, but on the incoming side, the view is just empty.

During the same commit, there were two other files with the same properties: they were edited in the old and in the new project version and a rename was done just in the new project version.
But for those files, my changes within the old version got automatically staged correctly.
The only difference for the file that is showing the merge conflict is, that there is a code line that was edited by me (*feature*) and also in the new version (*main*). So, it seems that it is correctly identified that there is a merge conflict introduced, but on the incoming view, it should be showing my edited version of the file *old.txt.*

Doing further research I found out that I can access directly the files from the git index. So I saved them as shown (as I did not figure out whether I can open the files from the index directly within an editor):

```
git show :1:renamed.txt > "C:\base-merge.txt"
git show :2:renamed.txt > "C:\current.txt"
git show :3:renamed.txt > "C:\incoming.txt"
```

As all of these files show the expected content (and especially none of them is empty) this makes me believe that there may be a bug within VSCode (Version 1.75.0) that causes the empty incoming view.

However, can I still somehow get VSCode to show the edited version of the file *old.txt* to appear in the incoming view to combine my changes with the new project version? Or is there another simple way to complete this merge conflict directly within VSCode without needing other tools?

My current backup plan is to use the files from the git index and merge them using a different tool (e.g. WinMerge) and copy this merge result in the result window of VSCode.

Comment: Are you currently stuck in the merge and wishing to resolve conflicts now, or are you willing to abort and try something else? If you're willing to abort, one thing that might help is updating your feature branch to rename the files in an earlier commit, and then it should be straight forward to update your commits for the new file. After that you can try the rebase again onto `main` which should show you the normal merge conflicts you're used to. (Note I'm not saying that is much better than where you are now, but it might bypass the issue you're seeing in VSCode.)

Comment: Another thing that might help: rewrite your branch (or make a new branch) with just your desired commits on it first, and then rebase onto `main`. Or, maybe make the new branch first, then do my previous comment, and then rebase onto `main`.

Comment: Also, if you'd like to finish without starting over, your "backup plan" isn't a bad one. I oftentimes switch over to different tools in the middle of merge conflicts if I like them better. (For example, I run all my Git commands from the command line, but I sometimes use VSCode for editing files. If I end up in an ugly merge conflict I might fire up Visual Studio because I like the merge conflict resolution options better than VSCode.)

Comment: @TTT Thanks for your suggestions and pointing out that using different tools is fine. So, for finishing this rebase I presumably will do it this way. But I still wanted to try out your other ideas. Creating a new branch (from the point where feature and main diverge), then performing the rename, rebasing feature onto the new branch and then finally rebasing the new branch on main did not cause the problem in VSCode. During the final rebase I just had to allow the empty commit of the file renaming, as the files on main were already renamed and the conflict resolution created an empty commit.